Edit DMN configuration from service using .NET Core
The project's architecture I'm currently working on is based on .NET Core. I´m trying to modify DMN diagram configuration (output policies given only one input)
Documentation from Camunda describe two ways (using Java API or Spring XML) to configure DMN diagram. 
Is it possible to send the XML (configured perviously in .NET Core) to processEngineConfiguration  bean in Java (that is, using part of the Spring XML's solution option)?
